# Make a new flag column when condition on i and i+1 row?

Tags: python, pandas

Make a new column that has value 1 when row at i has 'subcategory_click' and i+1 has 'add_basket_click'. So input is like:

```
event_name
Basket_Viewed
remove_basket_click
subcategory_click
add_basket_click
subcategory_click
add_basket_click
add_basket_click
add_basket_click
subcategory_click
subcategory_click
subcategory_click
subcategory_click
add_basket_click
add_basket_click
```

And output would be like:

```
event_name           Flag
Basket_Viewed   
remove_basket_click 
subcategory_click      1
add_basket_click    
subcategory_click      1
add_basket_click    
add_basket_click    
add_basket_click    
subcategory_click   
subcategory_click   
subcategory_click   
subcategory_click      1
add_basket_click    
add_basket_click
```

Looking for a pythonic solution, as the real dataset is pretty huge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `shift`

```
df['Flag']=(df['event_name'].eq('subcategory_click') & df['event_name'].shift(-1).eq('add_basket_click')).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 3):

#### `map`

- Use a dictionary where the only key is a tuple of the combination we are looking for.  However, can't just map with that dictionary because I want to default value of an empty string `''` so I want to leverage the `dict.get` method that enables me to return a default value.  I wrap that in a handy `lambda` and I'm just about good to go.
- I use `map` and I can pass multiple sequences (one for each argument of the callable being mapped)
- I use `*` in the `[]` context to unpack the `map` return value to a list

---

```
tup = ('subcategory_click', 'add_basket_click')
def fn(x, y): return {tup: 1}.get((x,  y), '')

df.assign(Flag=[*map(fn, df.event_name, df.event_name.shift(-1))])

             event_name Flag
0         Basket_Viewed     
1   remove_basket_click     
2     subcategory_click    1
3      add_basket_click     
4     subcategory_click    1
5      add_basket_click     
6      add_basket_click     
7      add_basket_click     
8     subcategory_click     
9     subcategory_click     
10    subcategory_click     
11    subcategory_click    1
12     add_basket_click     
13     add_basket_click
```